# jq, search for a 'sections' basing on a value of an attribute

Tags: unique, jq

I am new in this stuff,
I have input json:

```
{
  "2017-09-15": {
    "key": "stops",
    "node": {
      "lastUpdate": "2017-09-15 05:15:26",
      "stops": [
        {
          "stopId": 11000,
          "stopCode": null,
          "stopName": null,
          "stopShortName": "1000",
          "stopDesc": "Tom Tail",
          "subName": "1000",
          "zoneId": null,
          "zoneName": null,
          "stopUrl": "",
          "locationType": null,
          "parentStation": null,
          "stopTimezone": "",
          "wheelchairBoarding": null,
          "virtual": null,
          "nonpassenger": null,
          "depot": null,
          "ticketZoneBorder": null,
          "onDemand": null,
          "activationDate": "2017-09-14"
        },
        {
          "stopId": 1100,
          "stopCode": "04",
          "stopName": "One Three",
          "stopShortName": "1100",
          "stopDesc": "Big Wall",
          "subName": "04",
          "zoneId": 1,
          "zoneName": "Demo2",
          "stopUrl": "",
          "locationType": null,
          "parentStation": null,
          "stopTimezone": "",
          "wheelchairBoarding": null,
          "virtual": 0,
          "nonpassenger": 0,
          "depot": 0,
          "ticketZoneBorder": 0,
          "onDemand": 0,
          "activationDate": "2017-09-24"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I can get all stops by filter:
jq -r '.[].node.stops' json

but how to search for a specific stop, for example basing on stopDescr - exact name or containing a string?

thx.

Comment: I think I figured it out: jq -r '.[].node.stops | .[] | select(.zoneName=="Demo2") | .stopDesc'

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track ...

```
.[].node.stops[] | select(.stopDesc == "Big Wall")
```

#### unique

Regarding the supplementary question:

1) `sort` and `unique` both expect arrays as input

2) calling `unique` obviates the need to call `sort`

3) `unique` produces an array, so you might want to use `unique[]`

4) One way to convert a stream of (JSON) values to an array is to wrap the expression producing the stream in square brackets.

Here is an example:

```
[.[].node.stops[] | select(.stopDesc == "Big Wall") | .zoneName]
| unique
```

Comment: thank you. could you please tell me how to print unique output if I get duplicates processing my big json? | sort | uniqeue returns error. I know I could use shell's commands but why not jq? ~# jq -r '.[].node.stops | .[] | select(.stopDesc | contains("xxxxxxxx")) | .stopId' stops1
167
167
167
167
167
167
167
167
167
167
167
167